# How to implement snapshot logic in big query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, snapshot

Data available in Google stage table. I am trying to implement snapshot logic. I mean if data is updated, it should contain old record as well as updated record. For instance,

```
Name Project  EFF_START_DATE  EFF_END_DATE
Bob   P1      01-July-2020    15-July-2020
Jack  J1      01-July-2020    15-July-2020
```

After implementing snapshot logic, data should be like below,

```
Name Project  EFF_START_DATE  EFF_END_DATE
Bob   P1      01-July-2020    15-July-2020
Jack  J1      01-July-2020    15-July-2020 
Bob   P2      15-July-2020    31-July-2020
Jack  J2      15-July-2020    31-July-2020
```

It should contain both old record and updated record.

Comment: Not sure to follow you. What do you expect, some automation? If so, can you describe it? In addition, does the "start date" always start after the previous end date? In other words, does "end date" of task N = "start date" of task N+1 ?

Comment: start date is current_date of new record.

Comment: Is the start_date of the new record the end_date of the previous record (for the same name)? And which automation do you expect?

Comment: I am trying to do this in Big query. there is a record like below,                              Name Project  EFF_START_DATE  EFF_END_DATE
Bob     P1           01-July-2020    04-Aug-2020              Now if project is changed to P2, the table should contain both the records and update start date as today's date(04-Aug-2020)   and previous record end date as 04-Aug-2020

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery doesn't have a built-in feature for what you're looking for, so, you'll mainly need to program/operate your data as your use-case requires, for example, if you want to update the data, you'll need to make an insert operation instead of an update operation, to keep the old data.

Regarding of how to design your table to make the queries more efficient in performance and cost, I think you could look at the different [partitioning options](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#dt_compare) available and choose the one that better fits your snapshot requirements.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery is an analytics database, why you don't use analytics function?

Log only the date of the new project, as the start date and with analytics function `LEAD` to calculate the end date (start date of the next project)

```
with sample as (
select "Bob" as name,   "P1" as project,  "01-July-2020" as date
  UNION ALL
select "Jack" as name,   "J1" as project,  "01-July-2020" as date
  UNION ALL
select "Bob" as name,   "P2" as project,  "15-July-2020" as date
  UNION ALL
select "Jack" as name,   "J2" as project,  "15-July-2020" as date)

select name, project, date as start_date, 
lead(date) OVER (partition by name order by date ASC) as end_date 
from sample order by name
```

The result is

[image]

Does it work for you? Is it enough?

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot Guillaume!!